# Is there a way of simultaneously using different reference voltages for senors with different output ranges with an Arduino Mega2560?

Tags: arduino

I would like to measure different outputs of two absolute pressure sensors, one differential pressure sensor and a massflow sensor using an Arduino Mega2560 REV3.
The massflow sensor output is from 1-5V. As the output of the absolute pressure sensors is a current, I can adjust the range using a resistor. But the differential pressure sensor's output is between 0mV and 35mV.
In order to have a precise measurement I would need a reference voltage of 1V for the differential pressure sensor but for the massflow sensor I would need a reference voltage of 5V.
I know that the reference voltage can be changed using analogReference() but is there a way of using two different reference voltages for two different analog inputs?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the Atmega2560 has also differential channels with gain 1x/10x/200x so it might be used too. However Arduino core doesn't provide the interface for it, you have to do it directly. And yes, it's possible to switch between references, but it takes few millisecond to stabilize...

Comment: So I would need to always change the reference voltage between the measurement of the different sensors ? I would prefere if I could somehow set two different reference voltages for the sensors at the beginning and not switching every loop as like you said it always takes some time to stabilize...

Comment: You can use voltage divider for mapping `1V .. 5V` to `0.1V .. 1V` and differential channel with gain 10x to get  0 .. 0.35V (negative channel connected to GND). (Or 200x but it'd require to setup negative input near to the working point, as 0.035*200 is 7V)

Comment: I am really new to programming an arduino and I don't know how to use a differential channel. Can you explain your proposal more detailed or share a link about differential channel? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-use-atmega2560-ad-differential-channel/232545/9 but it's not very good one, as it's using |= for setting admux...